# Outlook Add-in Ribbon Custom Image memory handling

Tags: c++, com, outlook-addin, atl

I successfully created and customized my Outlook Add-in in ATL.
As this is a native program written in c++, I am profiling and hunting for memory leaks. I doublechecked most of the documentation and one part is not clear for me.

The buttons on the ribbon and context menu has the getImage callback expecting an IPictureDisp. I have something like this:

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap m_gdibmp;
...
STDMETHODIMP CConnect::GetButtonImage(IDispatch* ribbon, IPictureDisp** picture)
{
    if (!picture)
        return E_POINTER;
    else
    {
        PICTDESC pictureDesc;
        ::ZeroMemory(&pictureDesc, sizeof(pictureDesc));
        pictureDesc.cbSizeofstruct = sizeof(pictureDesc);
        pictureDesc.picType = PICTYPE_BITMAP;
        m_gdibmp->GetHBITMAP(NULL, &pictureDesc.bmp.hbitmap);
        CComPtr<IPictureDisp> pIcon;
        OleCreatePictureIndirect(&pictureDesc, IID_IPictureDisp, TRUE, (void**)&pIcon);
        *picture = pIcon.Detach();
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

According to MSDN [OleCreatePictureIndirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694511%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) "the caller is responsible for calling Release through this interface pointer when the new object is no longer needed".

Do I have to track this pointer and use some other callbacks when a context menu is closed and release this, or is it released automatically by the caller of my callback internally?